# How to updating conversion rate daily from Apex?

Tags: apex, multi-currency, currency

I want to update the conversion rate daily in multicurrency. Please suggest any solution for this as I do not have any idea where to update the conversion rate and how. Thanks in advance. :)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [DatedConversionRate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm) object to specify a dated conversion rate. I don't have a way to test this immediately, but I suspect you will need to make an API call back to the server, since Apex most likely won't support DML on this object. (use a POST to /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/DatedConversionRate).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for your response!

Comment: Hi sfdxfox, Please tell me, can we update conversion rate in bulk (I have data in the pipeline) in https post call if yes please suggest a way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jsmith You can use the composite resources to update 200 records in a call, or you could even use the sub-resource technique to update 5,000 (200x25) records at once.